# define PK before or after LOAD DATA INFILE

Tags: mysql, primary-key, load-data-infile

I neet to load >1 billion rows into empty MyISAM table. I'm sure all entries in the file are unique. Is it better to load the data into table with PK defined, or add PK later?

I have got 8GB RAM and SAS disc workstation with 5GB RAM limit to store indexes. There is noticeable slow down (from ~200k entries/s to 10-20k entries/s) when index has to be seek from the disc and not from memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before. If you add a PK afterwards then MySQL will create a temporary table to do so.

Comment: is it the case if I ommit creating PK, and just define simple index?

Comment: @Leszek Adding a simple index afterwards will also have MySQL create a temporary table to add the index.

Comment: I decided to remove PK. All I need is 2 indexes for column1 and column2. So I create table with indexes and then disable keys. Uploading is rapid (~1 million rows/s), but there is >1 billion rows in total (21GB). But to enable keys once upload is finished takes ~24 hrs. Is there a way of speeding that up? Column1 and column2 are UNSIGNED MEDIUMINT (3bytes). Will sorting before upload speed up that?